# iMac crashes wifi Network

Tags: network, wifi, imac

Router:  Airport Extreme (latest model)
ISP; local microwave
Wifi Network: iMac, 2 iPhone's, 1 iPad, 1 MacBook
iMac:  Sierra 10.12.3

Wifi works fine until I connect to network with iMac wifi.  It will either crash the network or reduce the speed to almost zero

Comment: "... local microwave Wifi Network?"

Comment: Live in the Country.  Use microwave provider for internet.   Wifi using Airport  Extreme as router connected directly to POE from microwave antenna.

Comment: Thought it might have been unintentional. Have you restarted the AE, and restarted the microwave router/access point?

Comment: Yes, and I replaced the AE with a brand new one, thinking initially it was the router.  Have also power cycled the POE.  I can plug MacBook directly via ethernet into the POE and get full performance.  It has taken me a while to narrow the problem to my iMAC (maybe).

Comment: Interesting, Wifi-off on iMac and internet works fine.  Wifi-on and network fails

Comment: Additional point:  If i use my cell phone as hotspot and connect iMac to that the Wifi continues to work fine.  It is only when I connect the iMac to the wifi network that the network crashes.